# Finding length and percent of line across polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, overlapping-features, length

I have a layer with several line features and a polygon layer which has land ownership information (so thousands of parcels).

I want to append several columns to the line layer attribute table (`"Owner_1"`, `"Owner_2"`, `"Owner_3"`, etc.) and populate those columns with the owner name (from a column in the polygon attribute table), the length of the line that passes through that polygon, and the percent of the line which passes through the polygon. So for example:

```
Owner_1: "Joe Smith, length = 20m, percent = 20%"

Owner_2: - "Jane Smith, length = 30m, percent = 25% etc.
```

In the case that a line only passes through one parcel, only `"Owner_1"` would have data filled into it.

Is this possible? Is there a better way to retrieve and store this information? I have probably 30 line features and the polygon layer has over 80,000 parcels so there is a lot of processing if it goes through each parcel to see if it overlaps with a line feature.

I tried this:

```
length(intersection($geometry, aggregate('line_layer', 'collect', $geometry)))
```

to append the intersecting length of the line to the polygon layer in a column I labelled with the line ID, then I would sort by `IS NOT NULL` and then extract the selected features. I would really prefer **to do this all in one step for each line** on a layer and append it to the line attribute table

Comment: length(intersection($geometry, aggregate('line_layer', 'collect', $geometry))) I tried this to append the intersecting length of the line to the polygon layer in a column I labeled with the line I.D., then i would sort by IS NOT NULL and then extract the selected features. I would really prefer to do this all in one step for each line on a layer and append it to the line attribute table

Comment: How many owners are there?

Answer (score 3):

If there could be an arbitrary number of parcels a line can cross, use JSON or a map type field to store your results.

For the JSON formatted string use this expression:

```
'{' || array_to_string(
    array_foreach(
        overlay_crosses(
            'Polygon layer name/id', -- set inside quotes the polygon layer name/id
            $currentfeature
        ),
        with_variable(
            'ints_len',
            length(intersection(geometry(@element), $geometry)),
            format(
                '"%1":{"length":%2,"percent":%3}',
                attribute(@element, 'owner field name'), -- set inside quotes the field name with the information of the owner (polygon layer field)
                @ints_len,
                100 / length($geometry) * @ints_len
            )
        )
    )
)
|| '}'
```

there are still some missing functions to manage dictionaries, so the JSON is produced just by formatting strings.

The structure of the JSON will look like this:

```json
{
  "Joe Smith": {
    "length": 20,
    "percent": 20
  },
  "Jane Smith": {
    "length": 30,
    "percent": 25
  }
}
```

If you want to use the map field just enclose the above expression in the `from_json(<expression here>)` function.

**Notes**:
*The lines and the polygons must be in the same projection, and the units of the length depends on the map projection.*

*Try to use a projected CRS.*
*To use the generated JSON string use the `from_json()` function, (e.g the following function retrieves the owner that have the longest distance of a line in its parcel)*

```
with_variable(
    'owners', -- set inside quotes the field name where you stored the json string
    from_json("Owners"), -- here we load the json
    with_variable( -- store the value o the longest portion of line in a variable called max_len
        'max_length',
        array_max(array_foreach(
            map_avals(@owners),
            @element['length']
        )),
        with_variable( -- get the name of the owner of this longest portion of the line
            'm_owner',
            array_filter(
                map_akeys(@owners),
                @owners[@element]['length'] = @max_length,
                limit:=1
            )[0],
            format('%1: %2', @m_owner, @owners[@m_owner]['length']) -- format the result
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: There is also a function for creating a JSON-like output: [`to_json()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#to-json)